# Initialize Gstreamer's PadProbeId to a default value in Rust

Tags: rust, gstreamer

I am familiar with Gstreamer but new to Rust,

TLDR; I want to be able to initialize PadProbeId to a default value before using it.

The details:

I have a Bin (containing audio + video encoders and hlssink).

I have been able to add this bin to the pipeline and it works fine.

The issue I have is the audio for the stream is optional and I want to do `add_probe()` only when audio is available. Below is a simplified version fo what I tried to implement

```
        let mut audio_probe_id: PadProbeId;
        let mut tee_audio_pad: Pad;
        if media_info.audio_available {
            // get encoded audio from the tee
            tee_audio_pad = audio_tee.request_pad_simple("src_%u").unwrap();
            audio_probe_id = tee_audio_pad.add_probe(gst::PadProbeType::BLOCK_DOWNSTREAM, |_pad, _info| {
                gst::PadProbeReturn::Ok
            }).unwrap();
            // link the audio_tee.src to enc_bin ghost pad
            let audio_sink_pad = enc_bin.static_pad("audio").unwrap();
            tee_audio_pad.link(&audio_sink_pad).unwrap();
        }

        enc_bin.call_async(move |bin| {
            bin.sync_state_with_parent().unwrap();
            if media_info.audio_available {
                tee_audio_pad.remove_probe(audio_probe_id);
            }
        }
```

However because of Rust compilers restriction to using uninitialized variables, it does not let me use `audio_probe_id` without initializing.

I tried to initialize it like this; `let mut audio_probe_id: PadProbeId = PadProbeId(NonZeroU64(u64::MAX));`. However compiler complains that it is a private field.

```
error[E0423]: cannot initialize a tuple struct which contains private fields
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rust way to have empty variables like this is to use `Option`, but in your case it would simpler to have a single conditional:

```
    if media_info.audio_available {
        // get encoded audio from the tee
        let tee_audio_pad = audio_tee.request_pad_simple("src_%u").unwrap();
        let audio_probe_id = tee_audio_pad.add_probe(gst::PadProbeType::BLOCK_DOWNSTREAM, |_pad, _info| {
            gst::PadProbeReturn::Ok
        }).unwrap();
        // link the audio_tee.src to enc_bin ghost pad
        let audio_sink_pad = enc_bin.static_pad("audio").unwrap();
        tee_audio_pad.link(&audio_sink_pad).unwrap();

        enc_bin.call_async(move |bin| {
            bin.sync_state_with_parent().unwrap();
            tee_audio_pad.remove_probe(audio_probe_id);
        }
    } else {
        enc_bin.call_async(move |bin| {
            bin.sync_state_with_parent().unwrap();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have a few more things I need to do in the audio block. I will use the Option().

Comment: Can you add more context to your question? There's probably still a better way to do it that will avoid you unwrapping the options all the time.